# .htaccess rewrite condition for specific page on sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure how to do this and couldn't find a suitable question/answer on SO so far (probably because I don't exactly know what to look for, so a link to a relevant question would be fine). What I want is to redirect URL's of a specific page on a sub-domain to an other specific page on the main domain. It should work like this.

Whenever the param. "category" is in the URL:
http://blog.website.com/category/categoryname
To
http://www.website.com/categorie/categoryname
(mind the difference between category and categorie)

When "category" is not in the URL
http://blog.website.com/post-name
To
http://www.website.com/posts/post-name

How should these rewriterules be constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These specific rules made it work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/posts/categorie/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com/posts/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following RewriteRules should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/category/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/categorie/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/posts/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense when I see it. I actually had to alter the rules a bit to make it work in my case:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/posts/categorie/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com/posts/$1 [L,R=301]